# Google OpenID (alt) failed to work: Were profile URLs migrated?

Tags: feature-request, support, openid, google

MyOpenId.com was down for at least 15 minutes just recently, and I thought, "No problem I setup my Google login as my alternate openid provider." I clicked on that logo in the login page and it told me it failed. So I started to panic and tried to recover my account to my gmail address, that told me there wasn't an account associated with that email.

So now, when I log in finally with myopenid up again, I see that my alternate openid was set to [profiles.google.com/myusername](http://profiles.google.com/dlamblin), and that my email was "myusername+stackoverflow@gmail.com". So I was thinking, hey shouldn't that have worked? When I deleted the alternate openid and added google as my alternate one, the field now reads "Google (myusername@gmail.com)".

That means at least [point #2 of the blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/) about Google's openids is no longer true.

So when did this Google openid url change? Shouldn't user's have been migrated if it was changed? You say >60% of the users login with Google's openid. Were they migrated, and maybe the alternate logins were not? And why can't the recovery email for a gmail address match either the `username@gmail.com`, or the `username\+.*@gmail.com`, or your Google (id@gmail.com) if you've provided one either as an email or an openid?

Yeah, I'll be better about remembering what exact address I used in the future, but it would make sense to me in this context to know about the special case for emails from a provider that provides >60% of the logins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So when did this Google openid url change? Shouldn't user's have been migrated if it was changed?

Google has been breaking a lot of stuff about OpenID and Google Profiles lately, mostly tied to Google+ but also related to the new multiple account support.

> You say >60% of the users login with Google's openid.

No, 60% of users log in with **GMAIL** OpenIDs which haven't been affected. Very few users log in with Google Profiles, which turns out to be a good thing given the nonchalance with which Google is breaking stuff on Profiles these days!

> why can't the recovery email for a gmail address match either the username@gmail.com, or the username+.*@gmail.com, or your Google (id@gmail.com) if you've provided one either as an email or an openid?

Er.. what? You mean the email lookup code should automagically figure out that you used plus addressing and account for it? In other words if you type this into the "I forgot my credentials, email them to me!" box...

> person@example.com

... it should automagically match ...

> person+stuff@example.com

... ??

That's really tricky.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the Google profiles issue. Yes I did mean that trickier search (it helps if your table splits emails at the @)[select * where wholeemail=input.given or (emaildomain = input.domain and emailname like 'input.name%')]; and I further meant that if I gave my email as me@hotmail.com, but I also used Gmail to log in maybe I could recover with either email address. Lastly I appreciate you adding in more backup openId credentials per account recently.

Comment: I think they might have fixed some stuff on profiles w/r/t openid as well. A high ranking Google person was pinging me on other stuff and I told him about this as well...

Comment: I can see the profile URLs issue have not been fixed yet . Hope they might fix it soon